# Ios cached ad hoc build

Tags: ios, xcode, caching, adhoc

It seems that ad hoc version is built from cached resources.

In simulators and in itunes-installed version everything works well, but when i'm bulding app for ad hoc, it crashes after launch. I've recognized from organizer/console, that one of my older versions is used when distribute ad hoc version.

I've done:

- clean
- delete derived data
- restart xcode
- restart device

but ad hoc version always remains old.

Any ideas how to clean cache for ad hoc?

Answer (score 0):

All Xcode build files are stored in `$HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`.

Either find the right folder for your app in there, or delete the whole folder content. It's totally safe, Xcode will recreate the files as needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Closed** Just rename the ipa file and app name, while creating ad hoc version, also change download links - this makes the deal. Really strange behaviour. I can suppose that it was some http cache.